# class number of groups and rings

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

The class number of a group is defined by the number of conjugacy classes.

The class number of a ring(specifically a number field or its algebraic integers) is defined by the order of ideal class group.

Is there any relation between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal class group of a number field is abelian, hence its conjugacy classes are singletons and the two notions of "class number" you defined coincide.

In my opinion a more interesting connection between conjugacy classes and ideal class groups is given by a theorem of [Latimer and MacDuffee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latimer%E2%80%93MacDuffee_theorem):

${\bf Theorem}$: Let $f$ be a monic irreducible polynomial with integer coefficients which has degree $n$. Then conjugacy classes of matrices in $\mathrm{M}_n(\mathbb Z)$ with characteristic polynomial $f$ are in bijection with the $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$-ideal classes in $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $f$.

Keith Conrad has a nice [blurb](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/matrixconj.pdf) about this result on his website.

Comment: Here the Z[a]-classes are defined from the action by invertible integral coeff.matrices, i.e. double copy of SL2(Z).

Comment: I mean SLn(Z). What I meant is that since Mn(Z) is not a group, it does not perfectly fit with the concept of conjugacy classes in group theory. However, I think it is a nice viewpoint for class group and relation to computation of class numbers via reduced quadratic forms, anyway.